# Char Array alphabetical sorting -C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I wanted to sort a char array in alphabetical order. I used this function:

```
int cchars(const char* a, const char *b)
{ char temp=*a-*b;
    if (temp>0)
        return 1;
    else if(temp<0)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;

}
```

and i used this:

```
qsort(larray,counter,sizeof(char),cchars);
```

it worked.

But i need to ommit the same characters from this array.
For example, if my array is:
{'a','z','f','m','d','a'}

it must return as :

{'a','d','f','m','z'}

How can i implement this? Please help.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is just a roundabout way of saying `1`, and is better omitted since it adds complexity for no gain.

Comment: @unwind - there could be a case for saying `sizeof *larray`, provided the qsort callback arguments are changed to `const void *`, of course.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem +1, totally true. I guess I'm getting tired of arguing that point, sometimes. :)

Comment: @unwind it is said to me by the teacher, it depends on the architecture which we used. Most probably it would be 1 but just to be sure.

Comment: @user3035291 Your teacher is wrong. In C, the value of the expression `sizeof (char)` will always be `1`. On all architectures.

Comment: @unwind is it differs at integers or doubles?

Comment: @user3035291 Yes of course, those can have varying sizes for different architectures. But `char` cannot, since `sizeof` generates an answer in terms of `char`. Thus, `sizeof (char)` is 1. Note that this says nothing about how many actual bits (or bytes) of memory are needed. See `CHAR_BIT` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be easiest to remove the duplicates after sorting, since they will be next to each other. Just walk through the array with two iterators, one that always moves forward and one that only moves forward if the next element is not a duplicate:

```
int i, j;
char prev = -1;
for (i = j = 0; i < (sizeof cchars); i++)
  if (prev != cchars[i])
    prev = cchars[j++] = cchars[i];
```

You may also want to fill the rest of your array with NUL characters afterwards:

```
 memset(cchars + j, 0, (sizeof cchars) - j);
```

That code, applied after the qsort, will convert:

`{'a','z','f','m','d','a'}` to `{'a', 'd', 'f', 'm', 'z', '\0'}`.

Comment: butthis is not working correctly when i tried "jkazajjka"   it returns "ajkjjjkkz" unfortunately.

Comment: @user3035291 Are you sure? Assuming the `jkazajjka` is sorted first, you'll have `aaajjjkkz` and when I run this on that I get `ajkz`: https://ideone.com/lDrxc6

Comment: @user3035291 Check the link I posted in my last comment. That site runs C code and shows the output